# How to output a reverse string using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, reverse, innerhtml

I'm trying to reverse a string and output the results using innerHTML. Nothing is output when I click the button.

```
    <input type="text" id="text">
    <button id="reversal">Reverse</button>
    <div id="results"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var input1 = document.getElementById("text").value;
    var button = document.getElementById("reversal");
    var result = document.getElementById("results");

    var reversals = function(string) {
        result.innerHTML = string.split("").reverse().join("");
    }

    button.onlclick = function() {
        reversals(input1);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Well, `button.onlclick` is only going to cause tears. Fix that rubbish up for starters.

Comment: can't argue with that haha..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you should do.

`input1 = document.getElementById("text").value;` should be assigned within onclick handler.

```
var button = document.getElementById("reversal");
var result = document.getElementById("results");

var reversals = function(string) {
    result.innerHTML = string.split("").reverse().join("");
}

button.onclick = function() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById("text").value;
    reversals(input1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you have a typo, you need to change `button.onlclick` to `button.onclick`. Next when you do a refersal it still has the value of `text` from when the document loaded, which is empty. You need to get the new value:

```
button.onclick = function() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById("text").value;
    reversals(input1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.